# Using conditional operator to run more than one statement will not work

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

```
function isPrime(num) {
  //TODO
  let primeNum = false;
  let prime = (num == 0 || num == 1) ? primeNum = false : (num == 2) ? console.log("2 is prime") : 
  (num % 2 == 0) ? console.log("num is divisable by 2 therefore is not prime") : { 
      console.log("number may be prime"); 
      primeNum = true;
      }
  return primeNum;
}
```

Im attempting a challenge off of codewars to test if a num is prime. On my final conditional I want to print to console and set a value to primeNum. It seems to work fine if i do one or the other but not both.

I know its possible to do by writing a separate function containing both statements and having it be called instead or that I could use if and else statements but I'm trying to follow best practices here.

Comment: Your current code doesn't seem to work fine: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: Haha yeah thats where I'm stuck it seems to work if i remove the brackets have just have the console.log but when i add the primeNum = true; it doesnt seem to work.      I'm not really sure what youre pointing out for me

Comment: instead of `: { ... ; ... ; }` use `: ( ... , ... )`

Comment: thanks patrick thats very helpful problem solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *have* to execute multiple things inside a single expression (such as inside one of the parts of the conditional operator), you may use the comma operator inside of parentheses. For example:

```js
const condition = false;
const result = condition ? 'foo' : (
  console.log('falsey!'),
  'bar'
);
console.log(result);
```

Or, for your code:

```js
function isPrime(num) {
  const primeNum = (num == 0 || num == 1)
    ? false
    : (
      num == 2
      ? ( console.log("2 is prime"), true)
      : (
        num % 2 == 0
        ? (console.log("num is divisable by 2 therefore is not prime"), false)
        : (console.log("number may be prime"), null)
      )
    );
  return primeNum;
}
const result = isPrime(4);
console.log('4:', result)
```

But this is not a good idea - it's hard to read, and is not best practice. Better to use standard `if`/`else` statements instead.

Comment: Thanks mate I'll use if and else statements instead. +1

Comment: Should I be using const instead of let in this case

Comment: Best to always use `const` when possible - `let` is harder to read when looking over the code later. With `const`, you always know that the variable is never going to be reassigned, so it's one less thing you have to worry about while reading.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some brackets should to the trick, or your interpreter doesn't know what belongs to which expression.
Nested ternaries is not exactly best practices. Consider multiple if() return x;